# Flutter 3.10 - 'window' is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking at the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/window-singleton) and apparently I can use `platformDispatcher` to get some data, however I can`t seem to get the following attributes :

```dart
ui.window.devicePixelRatio
ui.window.physicalSize
ui.window.viewPadding
```

Any idea where I can get without using a **context** ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first.physicalSize` work for me.
you can also try `PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first.physicalSize`

Comment: As I recall, going directly to PlatformDispatcher makes some aspects of testing harder... so we are encouraged to go through the higher-level WidgetsBinding instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `View.of(context)` to get `physicalSize`, `devicePixelRatio` and `viewPadding`

Comment: But i don't want to use the context, because i use them in a backlog function, not in the UI build

Comment: Maybe try `PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first.physicalSize`

Comment: Thx it works with that ! Do you know why now there is a list of Views and not olny one ?

Comment: Probably to support later on multiple windows, more details here https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/window-singleton

Answer (score 1):

If you need onMetricsChanged, you can use:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.onMetricsChanged
```